# Проблема с чтением файла nodejs

Tags: node.js, fs

Суть в том, что код ниже

```
const fs = require('fs')

const ReadFile = () => {
    let data = fs.readFileSync('a.txt');
    console.log('U liked '+data+' times');
}

const GetCon = (app) => {
    app.post('/Likes', function(req, res) {
        ReadFile();    
    })
}

module.exports = GetCon;
```

выводит ошибку:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'a.txt'
>
> at Object.openSync (fs.js:439:3)
>
> at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:344:35)
>
> at ReadFile
>   (/home/sepezho/Documents/Portfolio/src/Likes/Response.js:4:19)
>
> at /home/sepezho/Documents/Portfolio/src/Likes/Response.js:10:9
>
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (/home/sepezho/Documents/Portfolio/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.j
>   s:95:5)
>
> at next
>   (/home/sepezho/Documents/Portfolio/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
>
> at Route.dispatch
>   (/home/sepezho/Documents/Portfolio/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (/home/sepezho/Documents/Portfolio/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>
> at
>   /home/sepezho/Documents/Portfolio/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
>
> at Function.process_params
>   (/home/sepezho/Documents/Portfolio/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)

А обычное чтение файла, как ниже:

```
const fs = require('fs')

let data = fs.readFileSync('a.txt');
console.log('U liked '+data+' times');
```

Работает как надо. Я не могу понять в чем дело. В интернете решение такой проблемы еще не находил.

Comment: пропишите полный путь к файлу от корня проекта

Comment: Так а что вам непонятно? У вас путь к файлу неверный, это указано в самой ошибке. Путь укажите нормальный и все будет работать

Comment: Пкть указан верно, это точно.

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы заключалось в написании пути от корня проекта.